# python dictionary remove duplicate key values pairs

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a file from which I need to remove the duplicated pairs (marked in bold).

The input file:

```
AT1G01010 = 0005634
**AT1G01010 = 0006355**
AT1G01010 = 0003677
AT1G01010 = 0007275
**AT1G01010 = 0006355
AT1G01010 = 0006355**
AT1G01010 = 0006888
**AT1G01020 = 0016125**
AT1G01020 = 0016020
**AT1G01020 = 0005739**
**AT1G01020 = 0016125**
AT1G01020 = 0003674
AT1G01020 = 0005783
**AT1G01020 = 0005739**
**AT1G01020 = 0006665
AT1G01020 = 0006665**
```

Expected Output:

```
AT1G01010 = 0005634
AT1G01010 = 0006355
AT1G01010 = 0003677
AT1G01010 = 0007275
AT1G01010 = 0006888
AT1G01020 = 0016125
AT1G01020 = 0016020
AT1G01020 = 0005739
AT1G01020 = 0003674
AT1G01020 = 0005783
AT1G01020 = 0006665
```

So to remove the duplicates I first made a dictionary. After creating dictionary I tried this coding:

```
import sys

ara_go_file = open (sys.argv[1]).readlines()

ara_id_list = []
ara_go_list  = []


for lines in ara_go_file:
    split_lines = lines.split(' ')
    ara_id      = split_lines[0]
    ara_id_list.append(ara_id)

    go_id_split = split_lines[-1]
    go_id       = go_id_split.split('\n')[0]
    ara_go_list.append(go_id)

ara_id_go_dic = dict (zip(ara_id_list, ara_go_list))  ##ara_id_go_dic  (this is the name of the dict I have created)

new_dict = {}  # made a new dict to copy the data into this n remove the duplicate pairs

for k in ara_id_go_dic.items():
    if k[0] in new_dict:
        if k[1] not in new_dict[k[0]]:
            new_dict[k[0]].append(k[1])
        else:
            new_dict[k[0]]=[k[1]]

print new_dict
```

I don’t know where exactly I am making a mistake.

Please let me know my mistake or else if there is some other way to remove the duplicate pairs.

Comment: What is the output you get?

Comment: i m getting a blank dict.

Comment: how `ara_id_go_dic` dictionary is created? Can u just print this dictionary?

Comment: ok i ll add the coding how i created the dict.

Comment: Duplicate checking is the purpose of a Python set(). Give it a shot.

Comment: @rhkss: We can not create dictionary from the input file because same key have different values. go with set method.

Comment: @Vivek: i created the ara_id_go_dic from the input file. the dict created is: 
{‘AT1G01010’: ‘0005634’, ‘AT1G01010’: ‘0006355’, ‘AT1G01010’: ‘0003677’, ‘AT1G01010’: ‘0007275’, ‘AT1G01010’: ‘0006355’, ‘AT1G01010’: ‘0006355’, ‘AT1G01010’: ‘0006888’, ‘AT1G01020’: ‘0016125’, ‘AT1G01020’: ‘0016020’, ‘AT1G01020’: ‘0005739’, ‘AT1G01020’: ‘0016125’, ‘AT1G01020’: ‘0003674’, ‘AT1G01020’: ‘0005783’, ‘AT1G01020’: ‘0005739’, ‘AT1G01020’: ‘0006665’, ‘AT1G01020’: ‘0006665’}

I didnt get wht u meant by "We can not create dictionary from the input file because same key have different values."

Comment: @rhkss :  dictionary not contains duplicate keys. Just do ara_id_go_dic.keys()  and check..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set` to remove the duplicated elements:

```
>>> s="""AT1G01010 = 0006355
... AT1G01010 = 0003677
... AT1G01010 = 0007275
... AT1G01010 = 0006355
... AT1G01010 = 0006355
... AT1G01010 = 0006888
... AT1G01020 = 0016125
... AT1G01020 = 0016020
... AT1G01020 = 0005739
... AT1G01020 = 0016125
... AT1G01020 = 0003674
... AT1G01020 = 0005783
... AT1G01020 = 0005739
... AT1G01020 = 0006665
... AT1G01020 = 0006665"""
>>> for j in set([i for i in s.split('\n')]):
...     print j
... 
AT1G01010 = 0005634
AT1G01020 = 0016020
AT1G01010 = 0007275
AT1G01010 = 0006355
AT1G01020 = 0006665
AT1G01010 = 0003677
AT1G01020 = 0005783
AT1G01020 = 0016125
AT1G01020 = 0005739
AT1G01020 = 0003674
AT1G01010 = 0006888
```

Comment: Actually, string are already immutable, you'd do the conversion to a pair only if there was a risk of different formatting; otherwise `set(ara_go_file)` is sufficient.

Comment: @FrancisColas the result of `split` is a `list` and the lists are **mutable**, but yes its an redundant work ;)

Comment: You need to `split` the input into a `list` because you've put it in a single string, but in OP's case, it's a file, so that a self-imposed constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSV module and set:

1. Reader Input file by csv modules and create set of tuples. set is not save duplicate value.
2. Writer output in new file.

**input:**

Same mention in question.

**Demo:**

```
import csv
p = "dp-input.txt"
result = set()
with open(p , "rb") as fp:
    root = csv.reader(fp, delimiter='=')
    for row  in root:
        result.add((row[0], row[1]))

p1 = "dp-output.txt"
with open(p1 , "wb") as fp:
    root = csv.writer(fp, delimiter='=')
    root.writerows(result)
```

**Output:**

```
AT1G01010 = 0006888
AT1G01020 = 0016020
AT1G01020 = 0005739
AT1G01010 = 0007275
AT1G01020 = 0003674
AT1G01020 = 0016125
AT1G01020 = 0005783
AT1G01020 = 0006665
AT1G01010 = 0003677
AT1G01010 = 0005634
AT1G01010 = 0006355
```